# In PostgreSQL, how do I make it so that either column A or column B must be non-null?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a table with an "e-mail address" and "P2PMail address" column. The user is required to either enter an e-mail or P2PMail address.

If I set both to `NOT NULL`, then both must be filled in for a record to be created.

If I allow both to be `NULL`, then a user would be entirely unreachable.

If I set a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT` on both columns, then the combination of them must be unique, but it says nothing about what I'm trying to do... unless I'm mis-thinking here.

What is the correct way to accomplish this? I fear that the answer is something unpleasant such as "triggers" or something. (I was never comfortable using those.)

Comment: Are you allowed to enter both?

Comment: @Colin'tHart Good question. Hmm. I'd say yes. They may well want to *also* get messages in a more "instant" way but also keep a record via e-mail, so yeah, I'd say they can enter both and have duplicate notifications.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need a table-level check constraint:

```
alter table <name>
  add constraint either_email
    check (email is not null or p2pmail is not null);
```

If you're only allowed to enter one, but not both:

```
alter table <name>
  add constraint either_email
    check (email is null <> p2pmail is null);
```

The second form is possibly a little confusing at first glance: what it does is compare both columns' null status -- they aren't allowed to be the same.

The constraint can also be created simultaneously with the table:

```
create table <name> (
  ... columns ...
  constraint either_email check (email is not null or p2pmail is not null)
);
```

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I strongly prefer the != syntax. But I see that internally it's converted to <> so I guess it's me that's weird. :-)

Comment: The SQL standard defines `<not equals operator> ::= <>`. I think that it is a good idea to stick with standard SQL whenever there is no compelling reason to do otherwise. For one, it will make the answer applicable to other databases.

Comment: `For one, it will make the answer applicable to other databases.` - true **assuming** that the server provider has correctly implemented the standard - or maybe they thing like @Colin'tHart? :-)

Comment: @Vérace: all DBMS support the standard `<>`  (even MySQL and SQL Server). However essentially all DBMS _also_ support the non-standard `!=`

Comment: Is `<>` equivalent to a xor operation or are there context where the behaviour doesn't match?

Answer (score 13):

I like using `num_nonnulls` for this:

```
alter table the_table
  add constraint check_at_least_one_email
  check (num_nonnulls(email, p2pmail) > 0);
```

I prefer this because it can easily be extended to multiple columns.

If you also want to deal with empty strings:

```
alter table the_table
  add constraint check_at_least_one_email
  check (num_nonnulls(nullif(trim(email),''), nullif(trim(p2pmail),'')) > 0);
```

If you require exactly one non-null value change `> 0` to `= 1`